# iPhone - check condition for folder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, detailsview

I have a tableView which lists the contents of the document directory. It contains files(jpg, png, mp4, pdf, sql, mp3,...) and folders(they even have subfolders too).
Here is my screen shot.

[image]

where "SQLTutorial" in the list is a folder.

Then I have a detailViewController which opens the file when selected in the tableView.
Here is my screen shot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is I have no idea how to check the condition for a folder and make it list the subfolders in the next view. I am checking the conditions for pictures and videos like the following and it works.

Condition for a image

```
if ([detailedViewController.strType isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
}
```

Condition for a video

```
if ([detailedViewController.strType isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {
}
```

Condition for a pdf

```
if ([detailedViewController.strType isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
}
```

I am checking the condition for a folder like this

```
if ([detailedViewController.strType isEqualToString:@""]) {
}
```

But it does'nt works.

Any idea how to make it work? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check existance of folder as follows

```
NSArray *contentsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];

if(contentsArray==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"This directory doesn't exist");
}
else if(contentsArray.count==0)
{
    NSLog(@"Directory exists but doesn't have any content i.e. files or folders");
}
else if(contentsArray.count>0)
{
   for (NSString *path in contentsArray)
   {
      NSLog(@"Content Path :%@",path);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am already using this in my code. It lists the contents in my directory in the form of an array. But I can access to all the files in the directory, but have no idea how to check the condition for a folder to access it.

Comment: Its simple, have a BOOL variable called isFolder, check for every path, you have, as above if the path is folder i.e. last two conditions make the boolean variable to YES else NO.

Comment: Ok. But I am stuck in checking the condition for the folder. I can identify an image, if it is of type "jpg", and a video if it is of type "mp4". In the same manner how can I identify folder?

Comment: I guess you didn't understand what i explained above, I meant check whether that path gives you contentArray as nil or not, if it is nil then its a file and if it has array instance that means its a folder, thats it. why to stuck when you have solution..

Comment: It gives and error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Ya. When I use NSLog(@"%@", detailViewController.strPath); in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, it gives the path of each file in the console, when selected. But it terminates when a folder is selected by pushing the above error.

Comment: I see then some how your strPath is not having folder path, its nil, so I guess your condition (which you mentioned above) will also work once you find the cause of this :).

Comment: yup.. Thats wat I am looking for. The NSLog for folderpath even works in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but terminates when working in the condition.